# Setting a temporary environment variable for Batch from C++

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, java-native-interface

I am implementing a small pack of programs for batch users to use.
Almost all things in this pack is made in C++ and is called from Java.

How would I set a environment variable for the Batch file to use?

I have tried using this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL METHOD_NAME(JNIEnv *env, jclass theclass, jstring key, jstring value) {
        const char* thekey = env->GetStringUTFChars(key, false);
        const char* thevalue = env->GetStringUTFChars(value, false);
        std::string envvar;
        envvar.append(thekey);
        envvar.append("=");
        envvar.append(thevalue);
        _putenv(envvar.c_str());
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(key, thekey);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(value, thevalue);
}
```

However the Batch file did not see any new variable.
Should I use `system("set thing=value");`?

Comment: On Posix, consider [setenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html). On Windows, perhaps [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I am using Windows, and SetEnvironmentVariable does not seem to work, either.

Comment: @Dan SetEnvironmentVariable should do it. However, it sets only for the current process. If the process is not changing and its still failing, use GetLastError() to find more info,

Comment: I need to set it for the Batch file that will use my program.

Comment: This is my code: http://pastebin.com/Bp0nnRxR It just does not set the variable in the Batch file.  
This is how it works: `Batch calls Java which calls C++ that sets a variable for Batch`

Comment: You'd gain a lot of flexibility by switching from batch to PowerShell--which you could call from batch if necessary.

Comment: What I am doing is a project that makes game development in Batch easier. Batch is pretty important here.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I came to the conclusion that a child process cannot modify the parent process' environment.

Comment: does this help? [Changing parent process environment variable](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=658278)

Comment: @elzooilogico That's quite extremely hacky.